# How do I get the location-header of an Alamofire get-request?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

My iOS app sends a search with the get-method to a server that should respond with a location-header if the search matched only one object. I am never seeing the response with the location-header and instead I get directly the matching object in the response.

Does Alamofire download a resource automatically when it gets a location-header? I need to get the location-header first because I need the name of the file in my app.

This is the content of response.allHeaderFields when the call returns:

[AnyHashable("Content-Type"): application/luetus, AnyHashable("Content-Length"): 215271, AnyHashable("Keep-Alive"): timeout=15, max=100, AnyHashable("Connection"): Keep-Alive, AnyHashable("Etag"): "348e7-55a74cd064680", AnyHashable("Last-Modified"): Sun, 01 Oct 2017 04:36:26 GMT, AnyHashable("Accept-Ranges"): bytes, AnyHashable("Server"): Apache/2.2.12 (Linux/SUSE), AnyHashable("Date"): Sun, 01 Oct 2017 11:19:30 GMT]

As you can see, there is no Location-header.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the header fields, the `response` in your Alamofire request should have the header, you can access by:

```
response.response?.allHeaderFields
```

Comment: Added the header fields to the question. No Location-header.